# 2.1 as a secure access point?

Tags: 2.1-eclair, wi-fi, wifi-tethering

I rooted my HTC Desire 2.1 and I want to turn in into secure access point.

Is there any way I can do that?

I do want to make is secure so user has to enter password to get Internet access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what device you're using, [Android Wifi Tether](http://code.google.com/p/android-wifi-tether/) might work for you. It's also [in the Market](https://market.android.com/details?id=android.tether&feature=search_result), but the Google code page has the most recent versions . It supports WEP, WPA, and MAC address filtering (they refer to this as "access control"). You may need a custom kernel for it to work - this again depends on your device/ROM.

You could also try one of the [several other wireless tether apps](https://market.android.com/search?q=wireless+tether) that are currently in the Market. Some are free and some are not, but you can shop around a bit.

Yet another option would be to install [CyanogenMod](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/) if your device is supported, since it has the AOSP wifi tethering built in.

Comment: actually I am about to install CyanogenMod CM7 but want to do more reading about it before I preceed. Also I cannot find download link for CM7 for my Desire in http://www.cyanogenmod.com/

Comment: @Radek: CM typically refers to devices by their manufacturer's internal names ("codenames", basically). The Desire is also known as the Bravo, so you'll either want the Bravo build (if you have a GSM version) or the BravoC (if you have a CDMA version). [Here](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?title=HTC_Desire) is the Wiki page with the list of Desire devices to get you started, though.

Comment: great comment & great answer. Thank you. wifi tether works fine for me. The only thing is that it didn't work if encryption is on. But I can allow connections by mac so it's not a big deal.