# Can I link between android devices

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, wifi-tethering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [2.1 as a secure access point?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6240/2-1-as-a-secure-access-point)

I use huawei 8600 phone android 2.1 to use internet for cdma 800 evdo network.
I want to use glaxy tab 7" for internet using with wifi linking together.

Comment: Knew there were previous similar questions, but couldn't find one before! See also http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/43/how-do-i-share-my-wifi-with-my-ipod-or-netbook

Comment: Potential duplicates: [2.1 as a secure access point](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6240/2-1-as-a-secure-access-point), [How to share internet among 2 android devices?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4117/how-to-share-internet-among-2-android-devices)